# NSControl and NSCell: Manage the cell state the right way

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nscell, nscontrol

I have a totally custom `NSControl` with its totally custom `NSCell`. 
Now I want to implement some Mouse interaction. For example when user clicks over the control 
I want to change the control state to `highlight` so the questions are:

1) Where I have to deal with the mouse event? In the `NSControl` or directly in the `NSCell`?

At the moment I'm working with this code in the NSCell subclass:

```
-(BOOL)startTrackingAt:(NSPoint)startPoint inView:(NSView *)controlView{
    [self setHighlighted:YES];

    return YES;
}

-(void)stopTracking:(NSPoint)lastPoint at:(NSPoint)stopPoint inView:(NSView *)controlView mouseIsUp:(BOOL)flag{
    [self setHighlighted:NO];
}
```

2) Is the `NSCell` state automatically managed by the `NSControl`? If I set the `NSControl` stete to `highlight` it will be mirrored to the `NSCell`?

3) and what about the enabled attributes? 
At the moment I wrote this code in the NSControl:
And this code in the NSControl

```
-(void)setEnabled:(BOOL)flag{
    [super setEnabled:flag];
    [[self cell]setEnabled:flag];
    [self updateCell:[self cell]];
}
```

Have you particular suggestion to work with mouse event with a custom NSControl+NSCell?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

Create a NSTrackingArea, which will detect if the mouse got into your NSControl:

```
NSTrackingArea* trackingArea = [[[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:yourNSControlBoundsRect options:NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingActiveAlways owner:yourNSControl userInfo:nil];
```

Then you add your trackingArea to your NSControl:

```
[yourNSControl addTrackingArea:trackingArea];
```

In your NSControl subclass implement both

```
 - (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent
 - (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent
```

There you can do something with your cell inside your control, or with your control itself.

Hope that helps

Comment: Why have I to modify the tracking area?

Comment: You don't have to modify it at all. Its just a clean approach, because your NSControl subclass detects on its own when the mouse enters/exits and therefore it can act on it.

Comment: I need to simulate a NSButton behavior so I don't need to know when mouse enters/exits my control. I just need to know which is the right way to manage the mouse event on a custom control.  

At the moment I'm trying to manage it at NSCell level. Do you think this is not a good idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "the mouse event"?. If its only a click inside, you may need to override -(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent*)theEvent or -(void)mouseUp:(NSEvent*)theEvent. I would do this on the "Control" level, because if you add more subviews later to it, you don't need to change any code.

Comment: Thank you for time Boris,
Before creating this question I use exactly what you said in your previous comment. But MouseUp did't work as expected, reading some other incomplete answers I get that the right way is to work with tracking method in a NSCell. But this is the first time that I work with custom control and so I want to be sure that my choices are correct. You told me to work in a way that I already tried and that didn't work.